# Chrome extension with onmouseover change image's src

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a html code like following:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" name="img1" src="images/img1.jpg"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" name="img2" src="images/img2.jpg"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" name="img3" src="images/img3.jpg"/>
</div><br/>

<div class="preview" align="center">
    <img name="preview" src="images/img1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

The original idea is when mouseover to thumbnails image. The preview div will change the src to specific image. It works very well in local PC.

But if I bundle it into Chrome extension, the preview function doesn't work.

I am also tried the other method from [onmouseover not working on chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485580/onmouseover-not-working-on-chrome)

It still cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

According Chrome [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution):

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers.

That means your inline event handlers must be moved to external JS files.

Comment: How to I fix this? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @ErtuğrulAltınboğa put your code into external `.js` file and include it via `<script>` tag